# Una consulta sobre Ajax y porque no me funciona de esta forma el Success en Jquery a un ASP Core controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Bien aclaro que yo lo hice de otra forma pero tengo curiosidad por saber en que fallaba ya que quiero entender mejor como trabaja el $.ajax de jquery.

Yo tenia esta función que me enviaba un post hacia un controller:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Prd/CreateOrden', // Url
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            nombrecliente: $("#nombrecliente").val(),
            productoID: $("#productoID").val(),
            fechaorden: $("#fechaorden").val(),
            largotablero: $("#largotablero").val(),
            anchotablero: $("#anchotablero").val(),
            areaxtab: $("#anchotablero").val(),
            tableros: $("#tableros").val(),
            cinta: $("#cinta").val(),
            porcentajeused: $("#porcentajeused").val(),
            porcentajedes: $("#porcentajedes").val(),
            presupuesto: $("#presupuesto").val(),
            areatotaltab: $("#areatotaltab").val(),
            areatotaltab: $("#areatotaltab").val(),
            detalle: orderItems
        },
        asyn: true,
        success: function (result) {
            quitaesperar();
            if (result.estado) {
                window.location.href = "/Prd/IndexOrden";
            } else {
                window.location.href = "/Home/Mensaje";                
            }
        error:function () {
            quitaesperar();
            window.location.href = "/Home/MensajeJQ?Titulo='Error'&Mensaje='Un error no permitió enviar la información póngase en contacto el Administrador'";

        }
    });
```

Pero me daba problemas se ejecutaba antes que terminara de responder el ajax por lo que la función "quitaresperar()" no servia, lo que hace esta función era quitar ese icono que te indica que esta haciendo algo la pagina web. Además "result" venia indefinido porque nunca esperaba a terminar el proceso en el controller:

// POST: Prd/CreateOrden

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult> CreateOrden(OrdenModel Modelo)
  {
       var estado = false;
       int iId = 0;
       try
       { 

            var Entidad = _iMap.Map<orden>(Modelo);
            var result = _iOrd.Insertar(Entidad);
            //Convertimos de Task<Int> a Int
            iId = await result;
            ordendetail det;
            foreach(var item in Modelo.detalle)
            {
                 item.ordenID = iId;
                 det = _iMap.Map<ordendetail>(item);
                 await _iOrdDet.Insertar(det);
            }

            estado = true;

            return Json(new { estado = estado, Id = iId});
       } 
       catch(Exception e)
       {
            //SI USAMOS MODELSTATE CON ESTO OBTENEMOS LISTADO DE ERRORES
            //string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            TempData["Titulo"] = "Error";
            TempData["Mensaje"] = "La información no puedo ser guardada, contacte al administrador: " + e.Message; 
            return Json(new { estado = estado, Id = iId });
       }
  }
```

Si la sugerencia es cambiar "async: false" os digo que no :), ya lo intente y no me dio resultado, entonces como lo solucione y si funciono de la siguente forma:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Prd/CreateOrden', // Url
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            nombrecliente: $("#nombrecliente").val(),
            productoID: $("#productoID").val(),
            fechaorden: $("#fechaorden").val(),
            largotablero: $("#largotablero").val(),
            anchotablero: $("#anchotablero").val(),
            areaxtab: $("#anchotablero").val(),
            tableros: $("#tableros").val(),
            cinta: $("#cinta").val(),
            porcentajeused: $("#porcentajeused").val(),
            porcentajedes: $("#porcentajedes").val(),
            presupuesto: $("#presupuesto").val(),
            areatotaltab: $("#areatotaltab").val(),
            areatotaltab: $("#areatotaltab").val(),
            detalle: orderItems
        },
        asyn: true
    })
        .done(function (result) {
            quitaesperar();
            if (result.estado) {
                window.location.href = "/Prd/IndexOrden";
            } else {
                window.location.href = "/Home/Mensaje";                
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
            quitaesperar();
            window.location.href = "/Home/MensajeJQ?Titulo='Error'&Mensaje='Un error no permitió enviar la información póngase en contacto el Administrador'";

        });
```

Pero me queda la duda porque no funcionaba de la forma anterior, si alguien tiene una idea me la coment es por saber más sobre esto y si alguien tiene el mismo problema pues tambien ya tiene una solucion saludos.